# Apache Camel: creating simple POJO pipelines (put a POJO in and get a POJO out)

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, pipeline

I've just discovered Camel and it seems to be exactly what I need.
I have several building blocks which know how to process specific input data, so I want to create a very simple GUI for users to select building blocks, just chaining them one after another (sort of like Fuse IDE, but not that fancy. Just a linear list of components is enough for me).
I can't find **examples how to start a context feed simple POJOs in it one by one, waiting every time until the previous input message reaches the end of it's route, and then get another POJO on the opposite end**.
Or write it to a database / serialize to a file.
Googling only brings up some examples with Spring, ActiveMQ, etc. I just need the simplest scenario but figure out which URIs to use etc.

PS: I'm able to run this simple example (the only dependencies are camel-core 2.13 and slf4j 1.7.7)

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

// add our route to the CamelContext
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("file:src/data?noop=true").
            choice().
                when(xpath("/person/city = 'London'")).to("file:target/messages/uk").
                otherwise().to("file:target/messages/others");
    }
});

// start the route and let it do its work
System.out.println("Starting camel no maven");
context.start();
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Done camel no maven");
// stop the CamelContext
context.stop();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [CamelProxy](http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html). It allows you to send to a Camel endpoint.

```
OrderService service = new ProxyBuilder(context)
  .endpoint("direct:order")
  .build(OrderService.class);
```

OrderService is an interface which defines the methods you want to use to send:

```
public interface OrderService {
  public String send(SomeBean message);
}
```

Sample route:

```
from("direct:order").to("bean:someProcessor");
```

Send a message to the route:

```
String reply = service.send(new SomeBean());
```

[**Here is a simple working example**](https://github.com/sebastianvoss/camel-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/samples/camel/proxy/CamelProxy.java)

Comment: Thanks! I looked at the example you've linked to. But I can't understand how does CamelContext learn that when I call OrderService.send() from some random object implementing this OrderService interface, it should start the route? I thought I should be sending a message to the CamelContext first to initiate the routing procedure. Or is it just a convention to use the send() method, and is that convention described somewhere?

Comment: @chhh Camel will take care of the instantiation of the proxy. The methods in the interface can have any signature (as long as Camel has the required type converters). I put a sample for you in my git (see link in answer).

Comment: That seems to be a great example! How did you learn about Camel basics? The website tutorials seem to be [not enough for me]/[too complicated and using technologies that i don't know]

Comment: @chhh there is a book called *Camel in Action* from Claus Ibsen (core team member). This should be a good introduction to Camel.